# How do I remove non-visible elements from an entire document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to use Javascript and JQuery to make a copy of the web page's entire html and remove all elements that are not visible to the user. This is what I've tried so far:

```
$('html').not(':visible').remove()
```

However, it does not seem to work. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now you are only targeting the `<html>` element with your selector.  You need to iterate through all the elements and check their visibility like this:

```
$('*').each(function(){
    if($(this).not(':visible')){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Even more concise would be to just target hidden elements and remove them as such:

```
$('*:hidden').remove();
```

The jQuery API reference states that elements are considered visible if they take up space in the document.  So elements that have a height and width greater than 0 are considered visible.  This means we should instead look at the computed CSS if you are having issues with the above code removing things that are visible.

```
$('*').each(function(){
    if($(this).css('visibility') == 'hidden' || $(this).css('display') == 'none'){
        $(this).remove()
    }
});
```

Comment: This, too, seems to remove too much.

Comment: Elements that have a style of `display: none;` are different than elements that have `visibility:hidden`.  Can you clarify what you are targeting?  Both aren't visible to the user but they are targeted differently with jQuery

Comment: I need to remove everything not visible to the user, so both `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`. As far as I got out of the [JQuery docs on hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/), it only takes care of the first case. But the problem now is that it removes stuff that are neither `hidden` nor `display: none`

Comment: @BespokeSquirrel no worries you will get there soon!

Answer (score 0):

you are removing html elements which are not visible. you should remove its children.

try this

```
$('html').children().not(':visible').remove()
```

EDIT:
as Barmar said this only removes immediate children of html. use other answers to remove all elements.

Comment: That's not right. `.children()` only finds immediate children, not all their descendants.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right. so who up voted my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$("body :hidden").remove();
```

Comment: This isn't targeting an element

Comment: This seems to remove a lot of things that are actually visible.

Comment: Yeah, it considers everything in `<head>` to be invisible, because it's not rendered. Need to restrict it to the body.

Comment: That got rid of all the CSS disappearing, but it still removes elements that are actually visible to the user.

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: That would be too easy. :)

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. But it's hard to diagnose with that page, because `$("body :hidden`") returns 1125 elements, and it's hard to figure out which of them shouldn't have been returned.